# Xamarin.Forms: Grouping some Views of the same type

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Can I group some Views of the same type so I'll be able to apply changes to all of them at once?

Something like writing in **XAML**:

```
<Image GroupName="imagesToScale"/>
<Image/>
<Image GroupName="imagesToScale"/>
<Image GroupName="imagesToScale"/>
```

And doing in **C#**:

```
imagesToScale.Scale = 1.5;
```

Is it possible? I need to do it one by one?

Comment: You can define a XAML style for Target type Image and use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do in WPF XAML

```
    <Style TargetType="Image"  x:Key="scale">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                   <Setter.Value>
                     <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"> </ScaleTransform>
                    </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
     </Style>

 <Image Style="{StaticResource scale}" ></Image>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer @Dheeraj but I mean naming a group of Views to modify them all at once. What I want exactly is to scale them in an event in code behind using a group name insted of referring the images one by one. I don't know if it is possible so.